# Is the floating point operation "<", ">" commutative?

Tags: c, floating-point

Is the floating point operation < commutative. Is fabs(a) < fabs(b) same as fabs(b) > fabs(a) ?

Comment: You mean fabs (b) > fabs (a)?

Comment: yes, it is. more characters.

Comment: The result won't be the same even in basic math.  fabs(a) < fabs(b) is the same as fabs(b) > fabs(a), but not the one you show on your question.

Comment: But anyway, they're not commutative. In order for them to be commutative, fabs(a) < fabs(b) should be the same as fabs(b) < fabs(a).  Because you have to change "<" to ">" when you reverse the values, they're not commutative.

Answer (score 1):

If you mean fabs (a) < fabs (b) vs. fabs (b) > fabs (a): Yes, they are the same on an IEEE754 compatible platform. Even with NaNs, Infinities, positive and negative zeroes.

On some implementations, floating-point arithmetic doesn't always use the same precision. If you calculate x * y, and x, y are float values, the result could be float or double. So if you calculate fabs (x * y) < fabs (u * v), either x * y, u * v, both, or none might be calculated in double precision if all four are float. As a result, the two products might be equal or not (if they are close together in the first place). In that situation, fabs (x * y) < fabs (u * v) vs. fabs (u * v) > fabs (x * y) might give different results. But in that situation, that's the least of your worries. I don't know of any newish compiler where this would happen.

Comment: Thanks. Would '<' be associative ?

Comment: +Nice to have comment on NaNs. +1

Answer (score 0):

If you mean `fabs(a) < fabs(b) and fabs(b) > fabs(a)`

Yes it is